# access Amazon Neptune from EC2 windows

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sparql, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have an Amazon EC2 (windows) and an Amazon Neptune, both in the same VPC. I would like to connect to Neptune from EC2 using either sparql or Gremlin and don't know how to do this. I found

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-sparql.html

and

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin.html

None of the two explains how to call Neptune using sparql or Gremlin (is it from terminal or do they have studios of their own?) Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine you would use something like the Gremlin Console to connect to your Neptune instance. I think the documentation is pretty good: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/tutorials/getting-started/#_the_first_five_minutes

Unzip the console from the downloaded file and then just run `bin/gremlin.bat` (on Windows).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to switch to linux instance and use the page you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for how to connect to Neptune from EC2 using the Gremlin Console is located here [1]. You can also connect from EC2 using a program written in a language like Java. You will find additional links to samples of how to do that in the docs linked below also.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html

You can run the Gremlin Console from your EC2 instance in a basic terminal/command window.

If you prefer a more IDE/GUI approach you can also connect to Neptune from Cloud9

Hope this helps,
Kelvin